# Using Guice method injection not as setter

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is it a bad practice to use method injection, and not as a setter?

Say I just need one variable to perform a task

```
@Inject
public void doThing(@Named(booleanA) boolean A) {
if (A) {
   ..
} else {
  ...
}
```

Should I go through the trouble of retaining an instance variable?

```
boolean A;
@Inject
public void setA(@NAmed(booleanA) boolean A) {
  this.A = A;
}

public void doThing() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should: Guice can't know *when* you want that task to be done, and it isn't intended to do work on its own, only to set up things to do work.